# Geographical importance of Me'arat Hamachpela for Adam

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael, geography, parashat-chaye-sara

Does anybody mention the geographical importance of the Me'ara being situated about  40KM South of Jerusalem?

As it preceded Hebron as a city, why did Adam choose this site specifically for his family burial? Why not Jerusalem (Temple Mount), for example?

Comment: Using the Temple Mount as a burial site might have been somewhat problematic due to corpse tumeh, no? Imagine a Temple the Kohanim are forbidden to enter!

Comment: Does 40KM have any significance in your eyes as a figure, for in miles it is 24.9

Comment: @JoshK, you know that did come up in the days of Hizkiyahu, that they found the grave of Aravnah Hayivusi.

Comment: "As it preceded Hebron as a city" - I'm not following this. The Torah mentions that Kiryat Arba was known as Chevron. So, apparently it existed. As to when the Machpela cave existed, most likely prior to Havron's development, but not necessarily. It could have been a man-made cave that Efron dug, perhaps for his family's use before Avraham made him a good offer.

Comment: @DanF Ephron could not have dug it since Adam and Chava were already buried there.

Comment: Not an answer, but relates somewhat to your Adam & Chava question connected with Ma'arat HaMachpela.  https://www.hebronfund.org/inside-the-caves-of-machpela/

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks for the link to the fascinating article.